# Holomorphic and Harmonic $1-$ Forms on Riemann Surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be a **Riemann Surface**.

We say that a differential form $\omega$, on the Riemann Surface $\mathbb{S}$, is a **Harmonic $1-$ Form** if it and its conjugate $\omega^\star$ are both **closed**, i.e., $d\omega=0$ and $d\omega^\star=0$.

We say that a differential form $v$, on the  Riemann Surface $\mathbb{S}$, is a **Holomorphic Differential Form** if it can be locally represented as $dv=f(z)dz$ where $f$ is a holomorphic function.

Now, the question is:

What is the relationship between **Harmonic $1-$ Forms** and **Holomorphic Differential Forms**?

Comment: I'm confused by your definition of harmonic. What's $\omega^{\ast}$? Surely not the complex conjugate..

Comment: @Thorgott see the following link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_differential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is a completely different and much more common use of the term "Harmonic form" in [Hodge theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory). I'm pointing this out, because this is what confused me initially.

Anyhow, let $\omega$ be a complex differential form on $\mathbb{S}$. Harmonicity and Holomorphicity are both local conditions, so we may pick coordinates $z=(x,y)$ and expand $\omega=fdz+gd\overline{z}$ with smooth functions $f,g$ in these coordinates. Then, $\omega^{\ast}=i(fdz-gd\overline{z})$. If $\omega$ is harmonic, $\omega$ and $\omega^{\ast}$ are closed, whence $\frac{1}{2}(i\omega+\omega^{\ast})=fdz$ is closed. But $d(fdz)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}d\overline{z}\wedge dz$, so that $fdz$ is closed iff $f$ is holomorphic. Thus, the $(1,0)$-part of a harmonic $1$-form is a holomorphic $1$-form. Conversely, if $\omega=fdz$ is holomorphic, it is closed, but then $\omega^{\ast}=ifdz$ is closed as well, so that $\omega$ is harmonic. In total, holomorphic $1$-forms are precisely the $(1,0)$-parts of harmonic $1$-forms.

Comment: You might want to fix your $d(f\,dz)$.